# WCF hosted within ASP.NET application and Windows Authentication?

Tags: wcf, web-config, asp.net-3.5

I have an asp.net 3.5 application that contains an Ajax-Enabled WCF service.
I enabled windows authentication enabled for the application "OARInventory", the WCF services are returning:

> Security settings for this service require 'Anonymous' Authentication
>   but it is not enabled for the IIS application that hosts this service

[image]

What configuration are needed to make this service run under windows authentication?
My web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Treasury.IRS.HCTC.OARInventory.Services.IVOOARInventoryServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service name="Treasury.IRS.HCTC.OARInventory.Services.IVOOARInventoryService">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="Treasury.IRS.HCTC.OARInventory.Services.IVOOARInventoryServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Treasury.IRS.HCTC.OARInventory.Services.IVOOARInventoryService" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: have a look at this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36289/steps-to-enable-windows-authentication-on-WCF-Ba

Comment: I read that article, but its an example of WCF application...not wcf hosted within an asp.net.

Comment: but the client of the wcf service needs to be configured to use windows authentication too. What is the client of the WCF service? Is it the asp.net app?

Comment: Its just asp.net, no client.

Comment: I made a screenshot of my setup...wcf is used a DAL my asp.net thru an ajax calls.

Answer (score 0):

Ok figured it out...for anyone interested, just set authentication to your service folder to anonymous authentication.